# python temporary files

Tags: python, temporary-files

I have this code:

```
import tempfile
def tmp_me():
    tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tmp1 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    lst = [tmp.name, tmp1.name]
    return lst

def exit_dialog():
    lst = tmp_me()
    print lst
    import filecmp
    eq = filecmp.cmp(lst[0],lst[1])
    print eq

exit_dialog()
```

I need to compare this 2 tempfiles, but i've always getting an error like this:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] : 'c:\\users\\Saul_Tigh\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpbkpmeq'
```

Comment: That's not the full traceback.

Comment: true, i trying to use this in my small project. i'm writing a simple notepad using Tkinter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Error 2 is that the file is not found (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

`NamedTemporaryFile` has the `delete` parameter which is by default set to `True`. Are you sure that the file is not being immediately deleted at the return of your `tmp_me` method?

You could try using:

```
tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
```

Comment: Nah. Better to keep the object around.

Comment: +1. I think that's what going on. The local variables `tmp` and `tmp1` get destroyed when the function returns and the files get deleted.

Comment: @Ignacio, you're right, but I don't think this application's near complete yet so will hopefully differ by time it's done.

Comment: @Noufal I think more than the local variables getting destroyed it is the deletion of the files (which happens automatically) that are being referred by variables 'tmp' and 'tmp1' that causes the error to occcur.

Comment: @sateesh, exactly. Because `delete` is `True`, when the local variable is destroyed, the file is automatically deleted to. By adding `delete=False` this issue will be averted.

Comment: When the function returns, the local variables get destroyed. This calls the destructors on the objects and there (unless they were created with `delete=False`), the temporary files get deleted. It's the destruction of the local variables that triggers the whole chain of events that you've mentioned.

Comment: I already finishes a rant comment when I re-read the question. You are correct in hindsight, but this explanation is flawed. Destruction of local variables doesn't call a finalizer or anything, it merely changes the refcount. It's the fact he doesn't return references to the files (but only to their names, which don't have references to the file either) that matters.

Comment: Well, he just has one reference to them. Inside the function. So returning does cause them to get reclaimed.

Comment: Yes. But the way you explain it ("local vairables ge detroyed. This calls the destructors"), I had to think of RAII-style stack-based cleanup, as in e.g. C++. Which of course isn't remotely existent in Python.

Answer (score 8):

Have `temp_me` return the list of the two temp files, instead of just their names (so they don't get garbage collected), and pull the names out in `exit_dialog`.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't given the full traceback but I'm almost sure that the error is because by the time tmp_me() returns, the temporary files have been deleted. You return the names of two temporary created files and their objects named tmp and tmp_1 are destroyed when the function returns, deleting along the files they created. What you get outside is only names of two temporary files which no more exist now and hence the error while trying to compare them.

According to the documentation of [tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html):

> If delete is true (the default), the file is deleted as soon as it is closed.

Either pass default as False to your NameTemporaryFile calls, in which you should delete the files yourself. Or better and preferred method would be to return the objects instead of their names and from the exit_dialog() method pass the .name s to filecmp.cmp

```
import tempfile
def tmp_me():
    tmp1 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tmp2 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    return [tmp1, tmp2]


def exit_dialog():
    lst = tmp_me()
    print [i.name for i in lst]
    import filecmp
    eq = filecmp.cmp(lst[0].name,lst[1].name)
    print eq

exit_dialog()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the full error message I get

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'c:\\users\\imran\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpqh7dfp'
```

This is happening because reference to the temp file objects were lost when `tmp_me()` function returned, and temp files were deleted from disk when the variables were garbage collected.

You could return the temp file objects from `tmp_me()`, but then you'll have to close the files first before you could test them with `filecmp.cmp`